# Offset just one column in table that has 2 columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server, window-functions

I have a table with 2 columns that I will be joining to another in a query. I won't paste/explain everything going on with that join as it is a mess in progress.
In the first column is months 1-12, and in R78, there is corresponding values by month.
The join on month helps me take sales number * R78 corresponding row of month to give me a value.
Example would be if sales number is $4000 and sale came through in March for a long time employee, then it would be $4000 x 6. Issue I am having is that if employee started in April and their sales April was say $2000, I need to times that by the first month, which is 1.
I need a way to do this without hard coding any dates so that this query wont have to be updated in the future. I have the date part figured out but I need to figure out how to create that offset.

```html
MONTH   R78
1       1
2       3
3       6
4      10
5      15
6      21
7      28
8      36
9      45
10     55
11     66
12     78
```

Basically what I am looking for is if I want month to start at 4, I want R78 to start over at value 1.

```html
MONTH   R78
4       1
5       3
6       6
7      10
8      15
9      21
10     28
11     36
12     45
```

I tried various order by, offset, fetch queries but I can't get to where I would like. Datatypes are both smallint.
Examples tried:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.RT_R78
ORDER BY month
OFFSET (select count(*) from dbo.RT_R78) - 11 rows
```

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.RT_R78
ORDER BY month
OFFSET 1 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 11 ROWS ONLY
```

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: And please provide a [mre] with sample data, desired results and your attempt.

Comment: It's far from clear to me what you're asking, it looks like your table values have no direct relationship and should you be generating your month numbers on the fly? Perhaps using row_number; if Month 1 is in the same table row as R78 value 1 and you're just selecting `*` then these two values are always going to be the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a method that uses the window function `sum()` to help reconstruct the dataset starting from the desired month :

```
with cte as (
  select *, sum(case when month >= 4 then 1 else 0 end) over(order by month) as rn
  from RT_R78
)
select c.month, r.R78
from cte c
inner join RT_R78 r on r.month = c.rn
```

Result :

| month | R78 |
| --- | --- |
| 4 | 1 |
| 5 | 3 |
| 6 | 6 |
| 7 | 10 |
| 8 | 15 |
| 9 | 21 |
| 10 | 28 |
| 11 | 36 |
| 12 | 45 |

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/cf-kzVMx)

Comment: You're a wizard Harry! This is EXACTLY what I was looking for. Thank you very much - I have been trying for days to get this - I am still a novice with SQL and a lot of what I have learned in this job position the past year has been self learned. Much appreciated!

Comment: Glad to hear I could help you :)

Answer (score 0):

What if the employee starts in other months?
Here is my solution (as I understood the question):

```
WITH RT_R78 AS ( -- give me a table with the R78-Value for the 12 Month
SELECT * 
FROM (VALUES (1, 1), (2, 3), (3, 6), (4, 10), (5, 15), (6, 21)
           , (7, 28), (8, 36), (9, 45), (10, 55), (11, 66), (12, 78) ) AS t (MonthNumber, R78)
)
, Employees AS ( -- give me a table with 3 Employee and their StartMonthNumber
SELECT * 
FROM (VALUES ('Employee1', 3), ('Employee2', 4), ('Employee3', 9) ) AS t (EmployeeName, StartMonthNumber)
)
SELECT Employees.EmployeeName, Employees.StartMonthNumber, RT_R78.MonthNumber, RT_R78.R78
FROM Employees
    INNER JOIN RT_R78 ON RT_R78.MonthNumber<=13 - Employees.StartMonthNumber
ORDER BY Employees.EmployeeName, RT_R78.MonthNumber
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/EaxfpWyi